# Need output for following with Comparison of Current row and previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008R2. I have following table with Profile Name and T1 as column names, I need to add two more columns t2 and t3 based on some conditions

```
Profile Name     T1      T2     T3
----------------------------------      
IP Singles        0
IP Singles       90
IP Singles      100
Disputes        180
IP Multis       145
Performance     378
IP Color        420
Disputes        170
IP Multis       104
Insurance       340
Insurance       120
Insurance      1335
```

Conditions for both T2 and T3 columns are as follows:

**For T2:**

```
When T1 < 900 And
 Current row of Profile Name <> Previuos row of Profil Name then output of T2 will be same as T1 Else it will be 0.
```

**For T3:**

```
When T1 <= 900 And Current row of Profile Name = Previous row of Profile Name then output of T3 will be same as T1 Else it will be 0.
```

For example:

- If T1 is greater than 900 AND current row of ProfileName is not equal to Previous row of ProfileName then value of T2 will be T1 Else 0.
- Similarly, If T1 is greater than or equal to 900 AND current row of ProfileName is equal to Previous row of ProfileName then value of T3 will be T1 Else 0.

My expected output is below:

```
Profile Name    T1   T2   T3
--------------------------------
IP Singles        0    0    0               
IP Singles       90    0   90
IP Singles      100    0  100
Disputes        180  180    0
IP Multis       145  145    0
Performance     378  378    0
IP Color        420  420    0
Disputes        170  170    0
IP Multis       104  104    0
Insurance       340  340    0
Insurance       120    0  120
Insurance      1335    0    0
```

I hope I am clear with the question, Please help me to achieve that output with `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with the help of ROW_NUMBER() and CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  [Profile Name], 
        T1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as RN
FROM YourTable
)


SELECT  c1.[Profile Name],
        c1.T1,
        CASE WHEN c1.T1 < 900 AND c1.[Profile Name] != c2.[Profile Name] THEN c1.T1 ELSE 0 END as T2,
        CASE WHEN c1.T1 <= 900 AND c1.[Profile Name] = c2.[Profile Name] THEN c1.T1 ELSE 0 END as T3
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.RN = c2.RN +1
```

Output:

```
Profile Name    T1      T2  T3
IP Singles      0       0   0
IP Singles      90      0   90
IP Singles      100     0   100
Disputes        180     180 0
IP Multis       145     145 0
Performance     378     378 0
IP Color        420     420 0
Disputes        170     170 0
IP Multis       104     104 0
Insurance       340     340 0
Insurance       120     0   120
Insurance       1335    0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I was searching for. :)

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of SQL Server, you could use the LAG function in order to access data from the previous row. In SQL Server 2008 this is not yet supported.

A workaround would be using a self-join, where the join condition would be: link row n of copy 1 which row n+1 of copy 2.

In both cases, though, you need some way to specify the order of your table: a table is not a sorted list, so in order to run through it in some order you need either an extra column (which you haven't mentioned) with a sequence number, or some ordering condition (e.g. ORDER BY "Profile Name", T1) which is currently not the order you have.

--
Peter Vanroose
ABIS Training & Consulting.